# Invalid operation: subquery must return only one column — Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

i have pasted an image with wat o/p i need hope tht helps

[image]

I am trying to calculate the percentage of individual rows with total of one particular column.

I am able to achieve it in the `SELECT` statement with alias name but I have further calculation with the help of column `per` where I derive other columns, so I need this to be in an `UPDATE` query. I tried the below query but am getting the error:

> Invalid operation: subquery must return only one column

I don't have any unique id. I cannot use `IN` statements in this.

Where am I going wrong?

```
UPDATE a
SET per = (SELECT DISTINCT
             code,
             p,
             pd,
             ratio_to_report(SUM(amnt)) OVER (PARTITION BY p) AS per
           FROM a 
           GROUP BY code,p,pd
           )
WHERE per IS null;
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: You should not store values which you count from other values. Remove column PER from table and create view instead. Otherwise you are asking for troubles like this.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data and expected output. A [UPDATE with a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql) is most likely what you are looking for, but with your minimal code snippet it is impossible to fix your issue. But, in regards to your error, anytime you have `something = (select...)` the `(select...)` portion must only return a single row and column. You have selected multiple columns, which will also return multiple rows. How would all that data fit in a single row & column?

Comment: yes i thnk i have to go with join. will be great help if i get some suggestion on tht

Comment: i am able to achieve the percentage values in select statement but the per column stands as temporary and i need to use per column for other calculations further so im facing the difficulty

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update 1 column with 4 values.  Imagine it without the subquery:

```
UPDATE a
SET per = code, p, pd, per
WHERE per IS null;
```

Your subquery must return a single column and row.

Comment: i tried updating it with single column but still unsuccessfull

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery returns multiple *values* and multiple *rows*. You need to tell Redshift exactly how to apply all of the returned values and rows to the table being `UPDATE`'ed.

For example:

```
UPDATE tbl_a
SET tbl_a.per = code_sum.per
FROM tbl_a
JOIN (SELECT code
           , SUM(amnt) AS per
      FROM tbl_a
      GROUP BY code
     ) code_sum
   ON tbl_a.code = code_sum.code
WHERE per IS NULL
;
```

---

*Side note: For best query speed do not add `DISTINCT` to your queries unless you know you need distinct results. You are asking Redshift to perform an extra action that is not necessary as you already had a `GROUP BY` on the same columns. Often Redshift is able to skip the extra `DISTINCT` step but not always.*